# What skills/passives proc Tal Rasha stacks, but are not cast for Etched Sigil?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

I'm building a character with 6pc Tal Rasha's for 2000% damage

> - (4) Set: Arcane, Cold, Fire, and Lightning attacks each increase all of your resistances by 25% for 8 seconds.
> - (6) Set: Attacks increase your damage by 500% for 8 seconds. Arcane, Cold, Fire, and Lightning attacks each add one stack. At 4 stacks,
>     each different elemental attack extends the duration by 2 seconds, up
>     to a maximum of 8 seconds.

and the [Etched Sigil](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/etched-sigil) for casting my damage dealing spells

> - Your Arcane Torrent, Disintegrate, and Ray of Frost also cast one of your other damaging Arcane Power Spenders every second.

I need all 4 "elemental attacks" for Tal Rasha's, but I only want 1 or 2 "damaging Arcane Power Spenders" to ensure that Etched Sigil will reliably cast specific spells every second (in my case, Energy Orb and Black Hole).

What Spells/Runes or Passives fit the role of being an "elemental attack", but not "a damaging arcane power spender"?

I have verified Signature Spells will qualify for this role, however Ice and Storm armor does not. I also don't think Familiar works, but need to double-check that. I'm at work now so can't test every combination of spell/passive, but am not having any luck finding anything online so thought I'd ask to see if anyone else knows of skills that meet this criteria.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a list of skills/runes I've tried so far that **do not** get cast with Etched Sigil. Feel free to add on to this answer if you discover more.

**Adds Tal Rasha Stack**

- Any Primary Skill
- Frost Nova - Freezing Mist Rune
- Disintegrate, Ray of Frost
- Teleport with the Calamity Rune

**Does not add Tal Rasha stack**

- Anything from the Conjuration Category - Ice Armor, Storm Armor, Magic Weapon, Familiar, Energy Armor
- Frost Nova with any other rune

As a side note, here's some skills that **do** get cast with Etched Sigil, but have a fairly long cooldown so don't get cast too often :

- Hydra - 15s
- Black Hole - 12s

Answer (score -2):

Every skill is an elemental attack. It's worded in a way that confuses a bunch of people. Elemental attack basically means any skill that has an elemental attribute on it. For instance, everything that the wizard does procs AS some type of elemental damage. These are the following class categories that Etched Sigil falls under.

Anything in Secondary.

Anything in Force.

Anything in conjuration.

Mastery - Black hole and explosive blast.

The key is SPENDERS, so you would have these groups of skills that you can equip. However, I do not recommend anything on conjuration as you are not getting enough bang for your buck with skills from that category.

There are no passives that count as arcane power spenders, so I'm not counting anything in there in my answer. Those are just to enhance your character, not trigger Etched Sigil.

Comment: Conjuration doesn't work to trigger Tal Rashas from what I can tell. I've tested some of the Ice/Lightening armors, and some Famliars. Black Hole (Mastery) and Blizzard (Force) *does* trigger from Etched Sigil, although it honors the cooldown they have. I think Arcane Orb also works from the Secondary category too. So going by category is incorrect.

Comment: Alright, let me know. Make sure your Ice or Storm armor isn't the same type as any other elemental skill you have equipped.

Comment: I plan to do more tests after work today, but was hoping there was a concise list of these spells somewhere online. Someone on reddit suggested Frost Nova with the Frozen Mist rune works, so I'll be trying that too. And yes, I made sure my armor is my only element of that type :)

Comment: Cool. A link to your profile will allow me to see your set up too. I can also get a more concise list for you in my answer and list them all out. Ill do that after work

Comment: Latest build was [here][http://www.d3planner.com/980352880]. I have confirmed that Frost Nova Ice Wind works, but no other frost nova or other armor/buff/familiar works